# How can I step into pdb to diagnose this error on a production server? ProgrammingError(1110, "Column 'about' specified twice"

Tags: python, django, pdb

```
ProgrammingError(1110, "Column 'about' specified twice"

/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py

errorclass    
<class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>  
errorvalue    
ProgrammingError(1110, "Column 'about' specified twice")
```

This error seems to be happening here in django_authopenid/views.py:

```
if 'bnewaccount' in request.POST.keys():  
         form1 = OpenidRegisterForm(request.POST)  
         if form1.is_valid():  
             next = clean_next(form1.cleaned_data.get('next'))  
             is_redirect = True  
             tmp_pwd = User.objects.make_random_password()  
             user_ = User.objects.create_user(form1.cleaned_data['username'],  
                      form1.cleaned_data['email'], tmp_pwd) ### this is the last evaluated line in my code  

             # make association with openid  
             uassoc = UserAssociation(openid_url=str(openid_),  
                     user_id=user_.id)  
             uassoc.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to break into pdb, add this line in your code where you want to drop into the debugger:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

If you need to know how to have a stdout on your production server, I don't know that.